# How can ı change xterm to terminal window

Tags: xterm

hi ı am using codeblocks IDE when ı build a program ıt runs on Xterm 
but xterm window is so small ,letters cant be read how can ı make my code run on my terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the font is too small in an xterm, you can press <kbd>Control</kbd> and the right mouse button, a menu will show up and will allow you to select a larger font size.